# How to generate a different set of random values every time we run a program in C language in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

`srand( (unsigned)time(null))` is not working though I have include `stdlib.h` library too.  It says `time` is an undefined word as an error.

```
  int i, max = 16, a[16];
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    a[i] = i;
  srand((unsigned) time_t( NULL));
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {    // shuffle array
    int temp = a[i];
    int randomIndex = rand() % max;

    a[i] = a[randomIndex];
    a[randomIndex] = temp;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time_t` is the type, not the function. You still call `time`. "Calling" `time_t( NULL )` is constructing a `time_t` with a value of `0`, so of course you get the same random stream every time.

As the other answer notes, you need to `#include <time.h>`, but you also need to call `time` properly; your use of `time_t` here is equivalent to always seeding with zero. You need to change your seeding to:

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
```

which will *return* the current time as a `time_t` which you then cast to `unsigned` for use as the seed.

Answer (score 0):

The `time()` function is located in *time.h*, not *stdlib.h*.

Comment: I included that and changed time to time_t as per the syntax of visual Studio but still every time I run my program the values generated are same